# How to avoid new installed programs shortcuts to be public?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, desktop

Many programs install its shortcuts as `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` as default.
How could I force windows to always create new shortcuts in my user (admin) desktop, and not public?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the installer, some provide options to place shortcut,some not. But it is possible to move those shortcuts to ProgramData folder.

Comment: This I know. My question is there are some automatic ways to do this?

Comment: @RogérioDec Short answer: No.

Comment: Well, as a workaround, you can create a batch file with `move` command and run it when you need.